# Install 32-bit VB6 GUI design on 64-bit windows system

Tags: windows, user-interface, vb6, windows-7-x64

I have a GUI designed with visual basic 6.0 on windows 32-bit system. I am trying to install it on windows-64 bit system. When i install it on 64-bit windows system I am getting some problems in GUI like some text is missing on label or text-box.
When i install it on 32-bit windows system it is working fine.

I am confusing what might be the problem is it with the GUI design or installation?

Thanks.

Comment: can you be more specific? In general VB6 programs run okay on 64-bit systems

Comment: @Rob  I mean I have text on label like "calibrate this unit", on windows 64-bit system the text on label is like "calibrate", it is missing the remaining sentence. Its working fine on 32-bit system.

Comment: do both systems have the same resolution ? do you use a font which is not available on the 64 bit system ? is the label.autosize set to true ? could you post any code related to the label, and post a screendump ?

Comment: This can be screen dpi issue - your 32bit system may have 96dpi, 64bit system 120dpi or something. This creates various (font) scaling problems, esp when your labels are fixed size and exactly aligned to contained text or when textboxes are pixel or two too small.

Comment: @Hrqls label.autosize is not set before but now i tried by setting true then its worked but I have same problem with buttons and check boxes. Can you tell what i need to change to fix it for buttons.

Comment: @verendra have you solved this problem? i think this is the same issue on my VB app. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We've come across issues similar to this in the past, with certain control types/control settings not showing up in modern versions of Windows.

The work around we had was to set the Windows appearance theme to Windows Classic (looks mostly like XP). In the longer term we replaced those forms with controls that did work.

Answer (score 0):

Most controls don't have an AutoSize function, so you will have to do it yourself

Have a look at the TextWidth() function

The controls you mention all have their text in the Caption propery, so you can do something as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim strLong As String
  strLong = String(50, "A")
  SetCaption Label1, strLong, 0
  SetCaption Check1, strLong, 480
  SetCaption Command1, strLong, 480
End Sub

Private Sub SetCaption(ctrl As Control, strCaption As String, sngMargin As Single)
  Dim sngWidth As Single
  sngWidth = TextWidth(strCaption)
  ctrl.Width = sngWidth + sngMargin
  ctrl.Caption = strCaption
End Sub
```

This is far from perfect, but it might work in your case.

Some immediate remarks:

- TextWidth() use the font from your form to calculate the width of the text
- Not all controls have a Caption property. For a textbox you will have to use the Text property, so you can't the SetCaption function
- Some controls need some extra space, for example the checkbox in the checkbox control or the borders around the command button control. You have to figure out which margin works best

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to modify it.